# How to get a list of what responses are in one category with dplyr

Tags: r, list, dplyr

How do I see how to list out all responses in one column in R using `dplyr`?
I did Summary and got a list, but it includes (Other), and I cannot see what those are.

Comment: ``dplyr::pull()``?

Comment: Would I only put the variable that I am trying to pull in the parenthesis?

Comment: `df %>% pull(variable_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```
data(mtcars) # example built-in dataset

list1<-mtcars %>% select(gear) %>% as.list()
list1  # a list o gears based on the `gear` vector!
```

We can subset/filter by certain conditions:

```
 list2<- mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(mpg<12) %>% select(gear) %>% as.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear, but I echo what some of the commenters have suggested.

If you want to pull out each individual value in the column, use `dplyr::pull()`:

```
mtcars %>% pull(cyl)
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

If you want to count the values, use `dplyr::count()`:

```
 mtcars %>% count(cyl)
#   cyl  n
# 1   4 11
# 2   6  7
# 3   8 14
```